# How to find the number of times a digit occurs in a number

Tags: python-3.x

Trying to find the number of times `num` occurs in `x`

```py
def findNos(x,num):
    li = list(str(x))
    cnt = li.count(num)
    return cnt

x = 556785
num = 5
ans = findNos(x,num)
print(ans)
```

What's wrong with this code? I'm getting output: `0`

Comment: You convert `x`to `str` but still check `num` in it which is `int`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def findNos(x,num):
    li = list(str(x))
    print(li)
    cnt = li.count(str(num))
    print(cnt)
    return cnt

x = 556785
num = 5
ans = findNos(x,num)
print(ans)
```

You are trying to count num which is of type int. so you just need to convert num to string

Answer (score 0):

The argument type for `x` should be a string as all items in your list are of type string. In your code, it's set to integer for which the count method returns 0 as there's no integer value of 5 in `num`.

```py
def foo(num, x) -> str:
    return str(num).count(str(x))
```

```py
def foo(num, x) -> int:
    return int(str(num).count(str(x)))
```

Answer (score 0):

This line of code `li = list(str(x))` will split the list as follows -

```
['5','5','6','7','8','5']
```

So you need to search the string as mentioned in the NoobCoder [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66930810/10029809) or by directly casting `num` to string in the parameter of the function -

```
def findNos(x,num):
    li = list(str(x))
    cnt = li.count(num)
    return cnt

x = 556785
num = 5
ans = findNos(x,str(num))
print(ans)
```

With this you do not need to change your function.